# internal resource view resolver with multiple subfolders under jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi  I used Internal resource view resolver and my  structure of jsp are like
  jsp/adm,  jsp/icon,  jsp/iload,   like
and my annotation based controller will return string value based on condition
my problem is jsp  uder sub-folder is not resoled but it is under jsp folder is working
could any one please help me in this 
he is my code:`

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

my controller code is

```
@RequestMapping("/icrl")
    public String search() throws Exception
    {
        setMenuName(CommonConstants.ICRL);
        return "pgiCRL";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/searchCodes")
    public String searchCodes() throws Exception
    {
        String key=getSearchKey();  
        String query=getQuery();
        Map<String, Object> searchKeys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        if(query!=null||!query.isEmpty()){
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.DIAGICD9, getDiaICD9());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.DIAGICD10, getDiaICD10());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.DIAGNOSIS, getDiagnosis());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.PROCEDURE, getProcedure());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.SURGICAL, getSurgical());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.SURGICAL9, getSurICD9());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.SURGICAL10, getSurICD10());
            searchKeys.put(CommonConstants.REVENUE, getRevenue());
            list= (ArrayList<String>) iCRLService.getSearchCodeList(query,searchKeys);  
        }
        setSuggestions(list);
        return CommonConstants.SUCCESS;
    }
```

my view is depending on condition it may be success page and failure page so i need to fix the return value in controller because that is dynamic. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the subfolder name in the returning string value.

For Example, if your page "pgiCRL" is in admin subfolder then return "admin/pgiCRL".